# Are cheating questions allowed?

Tags: discussion

Many puzzles have rules, and i'm sure that we will get a few questions about "How to cheat?". Will we allow these questions? Some problems may have no solution, so someone might ask how the "cheat" and get an answer. Other cheating questions might ask how to cheat in a puzzle game, like sudoku or battleship. Where do we draw the line?

Answer (score 6):

No, because that's almost always completely subjective. Everyone could give their own opinion, and it would quickly grow into a useless pile of random people's ideas and arbitrary thoughts. For example,

---

How do I cheat in Battleship?

- Don't place the smallest ship until the end
- Move your ship in your mind when your opponent hits it
- Replace your big ships with smaller ones when they're hit
- Trick the opponent into thinking you were missing a ship
- Hide a ship beforehand
- Don't place your ships at all
- Distract your opponent with strawberries
- Decrease the size of the opponent's board
- Use a blindfold
- Switch the placement of the ships during the game and say the opponent must have messed up
- Shake the opponent's board
- Stab your opponent with a blunt stick
- Play during an earthquake
- Play while someone else is also playing
- Don't play
- Place your battleship in such a way as to make the final shot be 'E-0' (i.e. hanging off the edge of the grid)

Comment: That distracting with strawberries trick really works! Thanks!

Comment: I had a friend try to use the E-0 trick once.